# MySQL InnoDB Error 1034 Incorrect key file for table 'tableName'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm using InnoDB engine for MySQL and file_per_table setting is set, suddenly two of the .ibd files got corrupted and their size became zero Byte, now I managed to recover old version of these two .ibd files and I do these steps to recover my data

> 1- create an empty database
>   2- create a table the same as corrupted one 
>   3- use "`ALTER TABLE tableName DISCARD TABLESPACE`" 
>   4- copy the recoverd .ibd file in the data folder 
>   5- use "`ALTER TABLE tableName IMPORT TABLESPACE`"

but it gives me this error

> Error (1034): Incorrect key file for table 'tableName'; try to repair it

and when I try to repair it using `REPAIR TABLE tableName;`or even with

`mysqlcheck -r -u root -p databaseName`
`it gives me this error

> The storage engine for table does not support repair

Comment: Offtopic. This has nothing to do with programming. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Answer (score 1):

You took wrong approach to recover the table. The file's size became zero because of file system inconsistencies.

You don't need the ibd file, you need the data in it. So recover the data, not the file.

As we discussed you should scan the disk with [`page_parser`](https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb) and then extract records from InnoDB pages (`constraints_parser` from same toolkit).

Comment: thanks for the information, that sounds really good, i installed CentOS 7 on different machine with MySQL 5.7, and also installed percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb-0.5 and I have a copy of mysal/data/ that contains ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and also a folder for all tables with .frm and .ibd but as I discussed two .ibd files are zero size, my question is that how do I use page_parser is there a step-by-step turorial that I can follow it, and do I need to attach the hard-drive that contains database files or only copy of them is enough